# Ошибка последовательности передачи параметров в хранимую функцию из sql запроса

Tags: oracle, plsql

имеется хранимая функция:

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION test (n1 NUMBER , n2 NUMBER , n3 NUMBER )
RETURN NUMBER 
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_number (to_char (n1) ||to_char (n2) ||to_char (n3));
END;
```

Функция вызывается в запросе, при вызове объявляются параметры в иной последовательности нежели в  описании функции. Собственно запрос:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS n1
       , 2 AS n2
       , 3 AS n3
  FROM   dual)
, t1 AS (SELECT t.*
              , test (n1 => t.n1, n3=>t.n3, n2=> t.n2) AS nn
           FROM t )
SELECT t1.*,  t1.nn 
  FROM t1
```

В результате выполнения запроса, получаем ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как оказывается, функция вызывается 2 раза, вопрос заключается в том, почему при втором вызове параметры подставляются в последовательности в котором они объявлены в хранимой процедуре, а не в той последовательности, в которой они заданы в запросе ?

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit
- Production PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
- CORE 11.2.0.4.0  Production TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0
- Production NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: Из под pl/sql developer и в 19м оракл я такого не наблюдаю. Попробуйте изменить названия алиасов в with, что бы они не совпадали с названиями параметров фукнции. Знаю точно, что оракл может путать "поля" и "значения", когда они имеют одно и то же название(наблюдал как раз в 11м)

Comment: @SwaD переименовка алиасов в (a b c), не дала положительных результатов. Я думаю проблема либо с версией oracla или с настройкой самого сервера. Во втором случае хотелось бы узнать, от какой настройки может так "колбасить".

Comment: какая интересная бага!  а если поставить для функции флаг deterministic, то бага исправится?

Comment: @ESkri DETERMINISTIC тоже не поможет, так как функция все равно 2 раза вызывается. Ошибку можно обойти с помощью MATERIALIZE или же передачи переменных в "правильном" порядке.